# How can I use AMD modules with Sails JS

Tags: sails.js, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

Please, i need to work with [ArcGIS API for Javascript](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/) but i don't know how about use AMD modules with Sails JS.

I love sails js, and I do not want to throw my project in the trash, help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcGIS API for JS have two modes: [legacy code or AMD](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/79966).If not familiar with AMD,you can integrate your code with legacy code of the API.

I am not familiar with sails.js,if you have to integrate with AMD,you can refer to [Using jQuery in ArcGIS API for JS](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/framework_jquery.html) which might enlighten you on how to use sails.js in ArcGIS API.

Hope it could you.